# is it possible to use a variable as a reverence when referring to another tab in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| Sheet 1 (A) | sheet 2 (B) |
| --- | --- |
|  | # of hours worked |
| Dec/20-Dec/25 |  |

I am trying to streamline the process of a timesheet, whose sheet has tabs that have the pay period dates in them. in order to reference to the tab, it would be easier to have the totals sheet have a variable for the tab name in each category.

Ex. a2!B1

instead of Sheet 2!b1

---

just a separate thing, if it were possible to have the tab name also be based on the list of the pay periods it would make the process even easier, although I don't think it is possible from my research

---

I tried to do 'a2'!b1 and it didn't work, I don't have extensive knowledge of Google Sheets, at least not yet, so I don't know any other way of putting it in where it might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=indirect(A2&"!B1")
```